# Good test statistic

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

If we have a hypothesis $H_0$ and alternative hypothesis $H_1$, a test statistic $T$ and a data set $x_1, ..., x_n$ taken from some random sample $X_1, ..., X_n$, we use $T(x_1, ..., x_n) = t$ to decide whether or not to reject $H_0$. What I thought is, if we choose adequate $T$, we can make the probability of observing an event at least as extreme as $t$ ( $P(T>t)$, for example ), be low, and thus in favor of $H_1$. So if we choose an appropriate $T$ we can deny $H_0$. My question is: is this an easy job, is it reasonable to search for such $T$ and how can we say that a test statistic is efficient?

Comment: You are asking some good questions about the choice of test statistics.  Check out similar Questions at sister site CrossValidated.SE using search terms "power" and "test statistic".  There are tradeoffs involving the sample size, population distribution, and risks of Type I vs. Type II errors, and you might be best served by reading an introductory reference for statistical probability.

Comment: Will do! Thanks :)

Comment: You haven´t marked as accepted any of the provided answers to your previous questions. That makes me feel that you do not appreciate the work of the users who take time to answer.

Comment: Ooh, I did not know that I have to mark them. I will mark them in a bit! :)

Comment: @Peter There is no need to hurry. It is sufficient if you do it in a period of few hours or so.

Comment: Pedantry: you want to choose an appropriate $t$ rather than $T$ and especially for a  a discrete distribution "as extreme or more" translates to $P(T \ge t)$ rather than $P(T \gt t)$

Comment: @Peter I´ve noticed that you´ve accepted a few of the answers. Good job. Is the answer of [BruceET](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/221800/bruceet) too sophisticated? You can ask questions if something is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example. Suppose you suspect a die may give `1`s with probability less than $1/6.$ So you test $H_0: p = 1/6$ vs $H_a: p < 1/6.$  You roll the die $n = 120$ times and count then number $X$ of `1`'s. This test statistic is the sum of 120 Bernoulli random variables. Under $H_0$ (that is, assuming $H_0$ to be true), we have $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(100, 1/6).$

By intuition, if $X$ is very small (much smaller than $E(X) = np = 20,$ anyhow) we would reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a.$ We want the significance level of the test to be something like 5%. That means we'd reject $H_0$ about 5% of the time when the die is fine and $p = 1/6.$

Some experimentation in R (where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF and `qbinom` is the inverse quantile function) we find that we can have a test at significance level $0.0501$ or at level $0.0275.$

```
qbinom(.05, 120, 1/6)
[1] 13
pbinom(12:13, 120, 1/6)
[1] 0.02753237 0.05013085
```

Suppose we choose level $0.0501$ so that the 'critical value' of the test
is $c = 13.$  That is, we reject $H_0,$ if $X \le c = 13,$ otherwise not.

The consequence is that we will make a Type I Error (rejecting $H_0$ when it is true) with probability very nearly 5%.

Now, one way to judge whether this is a 'good' test is to look at its 'power'. In particular, we may ask what is the rejection probability
if the die has $p = 1/9.$ Formally, we seek $P(X \le 13 | p = 1/9) = 0.5344$ --- more than half the time.  We say the power against the alternative $p = 1/9$ is $\pi(1/9) = 0.5344.$ The power is the probability of ***not*** making a Type II error.

```
pbinom(13, 120, 1/9)
[1] 0.5343601
```

Similarly $\pi(1/12) = 0.8741.$

```
pbinom(13, 120, 1/12)
[1] 0.8740746
```

One can make a 'power curve' for powers of a test at level 5% against
various alternative values: With alternatives values of $p$ in $(0, 1/6)$ the rejection probabilities can be graphed as follows.

```
p = seq(.001, .166, by=.001)
pwr = pbinom(13, 120, p)
plot(p, pwr, type="l", ylim=c(0,1), main="Power Curve: Level 0.05")
abline(v=c(0,1/6), col="green2")
abline(h = .05, col="red")
points(c(1/9, 1/12), c(.5344, .8741), col="blue", pch=19)
```

In this figure the horizontal red line shows the significance level $\alpha = 0.05.$ The two heavy blue dots represent the specific
power values (for alternatives $p = 1/9$ and $p = 1/12),$ computed above.

[image]

*Notes:* (1) For a test at the 5% level, the only way to get better power against a particular alternative is to increase the sample size $n$.

(2) Some texts frame the hypothesis and alternative as $H_0: p \ge 1/6$ vs $H_a: p < 1/6.$ But then $p = 1/6$ is still used for the null distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can not accept H0 only deny. So the hypotese we want to prove true is what we call H1. And to say that the test statics is efficient you need the significance level.